# What is an update stream in C?

Tags: c, stream, language-lawyer

At n1256 7.19.5.2 paragraph 2 (with my bold):

> If stream points to an output stream or an **update stream** in which the most recent
> operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
> to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.

If there was not the word 'update stream', the whole paragraph would make sense. But I don't know what it is. Standard itself doesn't introduce it. Google search doesn't seem to work. What's the meaning of it?

Comment: Update stream means that you can perform both input and output on it.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen

Comment: Maybe streams opened with `+` mode, which N1256 describes as "for update"?

Comment: @MikeCAT Does N1256 have many versions? I didn't know that. This is my [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

Comment: @opol What i looked at is 7.19.5.3  The fopen function of the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "update stream" simply means a stream that is both readable and writable.

This is specified in §7.19.5.3 point 3 ([link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), bold mine):

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename,const char * restrict mode);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The argument mode points  to  a  string. If  the  string  is  one  of  the  following,  the  file  is open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined<sup>(237)</sup>.
>
> - `r`: open text file for reading
> - `w`: truncate to zero length or create text file for writing
> - `a`: append; open or create text file for writing at end-of-file
> - `rb`: open binary file for reading
> - `wb`: truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing
> - `ab`: append; open or create binary file for writing at end-of-file
> - `r+`: open text file for **update (reading and writing)**
> - `w+`: truncate to zero length or create text file for **update**
> - `a+`: append; open or create text file for **update**, writing at end-of-file<sup>(237)</sup>
> - `r+b` or `rb+`: open binary file for **update** (reading and writing)
> - `w+b` or `wb+`: truncate to zero length or create binary file for **update**
> - `a+b` or `ab+`: append; open or create binary file for **update**, writing at end-of-file
>
> <sup>(237)</sup> If  the  string  begins  with  one  of  the  above  sequences,  the  implementation  might  choose  to  ignore  the remaining characters, or it might use them to select different kinds of a file (some of which might not conform to the properties in 7.19.2).

Answer (score 5):

The term "update" in this context means a file opened for both reading and writing.

The term is used in the specification of the `fopen` function in section 7.19.5.3 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> *3* The  argument `mode` points  to  a  string.If  the  string  is  one  of  the  following,  the  file  is open in the indicated
> mode.Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **r** open text file for reading
>
> **w** truncate to zero length or create text file for writing
>
> **a** append; open or create text file for writing at end-of-file
>
> **rb** open binary file for reading
>
> **wb** truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing
>
> **ab** append; open or create binary file for writing at end-of-file
>
> **r+** open text file for update (reading and writing)
>
> **w+** truncate to zero length or create text file for update
>
> **a+** append; open or create text file for update, writing at end-of-file
>
> **r+b** or **rb+** open binary file for update (reading and writing)
>
> **w+b** or **wb+** truncate to zero length or create binary file for update
>
> **a+b** or **ab+** append; open or create binary file for update, writing at end-of-file
>
> ...
>
> *6* When  a  file  is  opened  with  update  mode  ('+' as  the  second  or  third  character  in  the above  list  of `mode` argument  values),  both  input  and  output  may  be  performed  on  the associated  stream.  However,  output  shall  not  be  directly  followed  by  input  without  an intervening  call  to  the `fflush` function  or  to  a  file  positioning  function  (`fseek`,`fsetpos`, or `rewind`),  and  input  shall  not  be  directly  followed  by  output  without  an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.  Opening(or creating) a text file with update mode may instead open (or create) a binary stream in some implementations